# OPC Client is starting new process when OPC server is added to OPC Client

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, client, opc

I have created opc server using grabox opc library. I have to connect, read and write the item value to the OPC Client. OPC client is Niagara Ax software.

OPC client can discover the opc server and can connect to it and display Server's item. But the problem is when opc client connects to opc server it creates its own new process. I have tested my opc server with another sample opc client and only one process is created with that sample opc client.

I am not able to read and write with the Niagara OPC client and i think it is because of creation of two process and because of which they are not linked with each other to perform read and write operation. When i tested with sample opc client, where only one process is seen, it can perform read and write operation with opc server.

So, can some one help how to create only one process so that i can perform read and write operation in opc server.

Initially when i run my application "Minopc.exe" is run by username:Sika and when Niagara opc client is connected with opc server another process, "Minopc.exe" is run by username: SYSTEM.

Actually i searched about process and thread in c++ . But i could not get a way out to bind these both processes into one or block one of the process .

Answer (score 0):

Graybox OPC Library does not support OPC Data Access 3.00.

Are you sure you have well configured your Niagara OPC Client ?

Answer (score 0):

Your client cannot access the server that is running, so a new server process is started. Try to configure both clients to use the same user account.

It may also work, if you manage to configure the DCOM properties for the server so that it accepts connections from SYSTEM account.